# float text container with css and media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a problem with the displaying from two containers with css.  The first container has a background image. The second container is text only.

The position of the second container is on the top the first container.
but by the displaying in small media queries, I would displaying the second container after the first container.

```css
#back,
#back1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="back">
  <div id="text">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>

<hr />

<div id="back1"></div>

<div id="text">
    Hello
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put them both in a relatively positioned container and then add a media query to absolutely position the the text for larger screens:

```css
#back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="back"></div>
  <div id="text">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```